# How to compare adjacent array values and potentially delete one or join elements of two

Tags: arrays, ruby, concatenation

How would I compare adjacent elements in:

```
line = 'Aug 2013-Mar 2014; Apr 2013-Aug 2013; Jun 2014-Aug 2015; Apr 2003-Nov 2004; Apr 2014-Jan 2015'
```

to check whether:

- The first year value in the proceeding element is less than or equal to the last year value in the current element, and
- The first month value in the proceeding element is less than, equal to, or one greater than the month value in the current element

If the condition is met, I would like to move the latter two values from the proceeding element to the current element in a combination or hard set value and delete the proceeding element.

```
#Expected result => [[2003, 4, 2004, 11], [2013, 4, 2015, 8]]
```

This is my attempt:

```
require 'date'
line = line.split(/[-,;]/)
months = []
years = []
line.each do |x|
    x = DateTime.parse(x)
    months <<  x.mon
    years << x.year
end
years.zip(months).flatten.each_slice(4).to_a.sort_by{|x| [x[2],x[3]]}
#=> [[2003, 4, 2004, 11], [2013, 4, 2013, 8], [2013, 8, 2014, 3], [2014, 4, 2015, 1], [2014, 6, 2015, 8]]
```

Comment: I don't understand. You seem to know precisely what you need to do. Why don't you just... do it?

Comment: I only know how to do it by iterating through the array using i += 1 and a bunch of conditions, I was wondering if there was a better way @SergioTulentsev

Comment: It would be fine to see an expected result.

Comment: @Chris: `.each_cons(2)` will help you immensely with getting every adjacent pair. Try that.

Answer (score 0):

Well, conditions are cumbersome, so I expect you are able to write a proper condition to select elements. The first step would be to get dates:

```
line = 'Aug 2013-Mar 2014; Apr 2013-Aug 2013; ' +
       'Jun 2014-Aug 2015; Apr 2003-Nov 2004; Apr 2014-Jan 2015'
dates = line.split(/\s*[,;]\s*/).map do |s| 
          s.split('-')
        end.map do |d1, d2| 
          [Date.parse(d1), Date.parse(d2)]
        end
#⇒ [[#<Date: 2013-08-01 ((2456506j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, 
     #<Date: 2014-03-01 .......]]

dates.map { |dd| dd.inject(&:-) }
#⇒ [(-212/1), (-122/1), (-426/1), (-580/1), (-275/1)]
```

As I understood, you want to select something basing on date difference. Here you go (e. g. for one year):

```
dates.select do |dd|
  dd.inject(&:-) < -365
end.map do |d1, d2| 
  [d1.year, d1.month, d2.year, d2.month]
end
#⇒ [[2014, 6, 2015, 8], [2003, 4, 2004, 11]]
```